# How to move data from sale.order (order_line) to stock.picking(pack_operation_product_ids)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

How does data from the field `order_line` (sale.order.line) to the field `pack_operation_product_ids` (stock move)?
I've made a custome field in each field..
so when a sale order on the approve data, which I made in move_line it participated also in the field are filled I made on `pack_operation_product_ids`.

i'm use odoo10

thx

Answer (score 1):

The values for creating procurement is returned from method ***_prepare_order_line_procurement*** in sale order line. If you need to pass your custom fields, you need to return your field values from this method.

example:

```
_inherit = 'sale.order.line'

@api.multi
def _prepare_order_line_procurement(self, group_id=False):
    vals = super(SaleOrderLine, self)._prepare_order_line_procurement(group_id=group_id)
    vals.update({
        'your_field_1': self.your_field_1_in_sale_order_line,
        'your_field_2': self.your_field_2_in_sale_order_line,
    })
    return vals
```

Comment: still can not. I would like to move the description of the product on sale order (sale.order.line) to the delivery order line (stock.move).

Comment: and sir, your_field_2 that's supposed to mean what? I only made 1 custome field in stock move to accommodate the existing product description at sale.order.line.

Comment: if you have only one field just ignore field_2(you can pass any number of fields from this method).

Comment: also make sure the view for stock move have your field

Comment: I've tried it. but still can not. is there more that should be changed?